# Paid app uninstalls after reboot of the device

Tags: google-play-store, installation, uninstallation

I have one paid app, which is uninstalls after a reboot of the device. So, I have to re-install it from Google Play after every boot. All other apps are still installed.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: What is the name of the paid app?

Comment: worldhistory. worldhistory trial is also needed and has no problems.